# How can I change svn status?

Tags: svn, addition

Sometimes I want to add a folder into svn with `svn add my_folder` but then I change my mind and don't want to commit this. It seems that svn remembers this pending addition forever! If I make a mistake and move, remove or rename the file, `svn status` will still show that this folder is scheduled for addition after the next `commit` and will produce an error.

I have tried `svn update` and a clean checkout. The problem is, that `svn update` usually doesn't work, `svn checkout` not always works and if it does, it is very troublesome.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
svn revert --recursive my_folder
```

It will undo your `svn add` recursively

Answer (score 1):

`svn delete --keep-local` does the trick for files and also should for directories.

Comment: I don't think delete will work until the folder has already been committed.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
svn revert my_folder
```

To make svn forget you ever did an `add`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
svn revert my_folder
```

That should back out the addition of the folder.